# Java nested for loop incrementing second loop by first for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops, pre-increment

Hi I'm learning Java and found a solution that is pretty neat,
but I'm interested in a particular line of code in the 2nd for loop.
I wouldn't know who to ask because I'm not in school for Java yet so I'm asking here,
but anyway:

```
for (int i = 0; i < BRICKS_IN_BASE + (-h); i++)
```

Does this mean that 'repeat `i` for this number of times' is added' to '`h` minus 1'? More specifically what is `(-h)`? Is it a pre-increment? And why is it in parenthesis?

It's again used in declaring the variable `x`.

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Pyramid extends GraphicsProgram {

    /** Width of each brick in pixels */
    private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;

    /** Width of each brick in pixels */
    private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;

    /** Number of bricks in the base of the pyramid */
    private static final int BRICKS_IN_BASE = 15;

    public void run() {
        for (int h = 0; h < BRICKS_IN_BASE; h++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < BRICKS_IN_BASE + (-h); i++)
            {
                int k = i * BRICK_WIDTH;
                int m = h * BRICK_HEIGHT;
                int x = ((getWidth() - ((BRICKS_IN_BASE + (-h)) * BRICK_WIDTH)) / 2) + k;
                int y = getHeight() - ((BRICK_HEIGHT + 1) + m);
                GRect brick = new GRect (x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
                add(brick);
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe type `int i = 1; System.out.println(1 + (-i));` into your computer and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < BRICKS_IN_BASE + (-h); i++)
```

is really (the (-h) is simply -1*h)

```
for (int i = 0; i < (BRICKS_IN_BASE  - h); i++)
```

due to [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)